# Substituting vs Relabelling

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If we were told $n^4 + 1$ = ($n^2 + n\sqrt2+1$)($n^2 - n\sqrt2 + 1$) for all real $n$, we can substitute $n = \frac{m}{\sqrt2}$ (lets call this step 1)  for some  real number $m$, and get $\frac{m^4}{4} + 1$ $=$ ($\frac{m^2}{2} + m +1)$$(\frac{m^2}{2} - m + 1)$, multiplying by $4$ gives, $m^4 + 4$ $=$ $(m^2 + 2m +2)(m^2 - 2m + 2)$ for some real number $m$. Now it is total valid to replace $m$ with $n$ (lets call this step 2) , allowing us to get $n^4 + 4$ $=$ $(n^2 + 2n +2)(n^2 - 2n + 2)$ for some real number $n$, now there is a subtle difference between step 1 and 2, could someone explain the difference and the validity of step 2? What I mean by this is we know  $n = \frac{m}{\sqrt2}$, so in step 2 we cant have said $n = m$, as that is a contradiction, yet its still a valid move.
Thanks for all your help in advance.

Comment: is this on an Oxford entrance exam?

Comment: yes the question is from a MAT paper but the underling issue is the relabelling/ substitution, this is just the most prominent example i have seen, so I used it. If this is not allowed/forbidden I will gladly take the question down.

Comment: You can't substitute n by m, because already you have defined n, so that would violate the auto-identity principle.

Comment: How is that a "valid move"? As tac said in the previous comment $n$ is already defined, you can't make such substition.

Comment: The place I first encountered this question uses the $m$ to $n$ trick, so is that all it is, a trick? I would not expect Oxford University to use tricks, so I assumed there was validity there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't substituting $n$ by $m$ "because $n = m$", since they're clearly different. What is happening here is kinda a "without loss of generality" argument.

Maybe a better way to put it would be: for $m$, the second equation is valid, and since the first one is valid for **all** real $n$, it is particularly valid for $m$, so that

$m^4 + 1= (m^2 + m\sqrt2+1)(m^2 - m\sqrt2+1)$

$m^4+4 = (m^2 + 2m +2)(m^2 - 2m + 2)$

Now, you could have started with some real $p$ such that $p = \frac{n}{\sqrt2}$, since the first equation is valid for all real $n$, and then the equations I wrote above would be valid for $n$.

Comment: Alright, so there is a clear difference between substitution (such as $p = \frac{n}{\sqrt2}$) and the whole swap $p$ for $m$ thing.
I kind of get it now, probably better to just not think of it too much, and "forget" about the substitution when you swap variables at the end, after all, they are just letters.

Comment: Yes, there is a difference. Step 1 is just "combining two equations" (with substitution), and step 2 is using the fact that the equations 1 is valid for all reals. More precisely, it uses the fact that it is valid for $p =\frac{n}{\sqrt2}$, whereas step 1 doesn't need such a thing

Answer (score 1):

Consider the simpler exercise :

Let

$$n+1=n+1$$

which is correct $\forall n\in\mathbb R$ .

Then, substituting $n=2m$, you have :

$$2m+1=2m+1$$

which is also correct  $\forall m\in\mathbb R$ .

Since, the above statement is true *for all* $m\in\mathbb R$, this is also true *for all* $n\in\mathbb R$ . Therefore, we have :

$$2n+1=2n+1$$

Does this imply $n=2n\thinspace\thinspace ?$

The answer is no. Because, in the last step, basically we  used $m\color{red}{\longmapsto} n$, not $m\color{red}{=}n$ . Since we have *already* defined the variable $n$, therefore we can *not* use the *same* variable under the *different* definition .

For instance, when we integrate some function we can perfectly write :

$$\int f(x)\mathrm{d}x=F(x)+2C$$

However, we can also write this fact as follows :

$$\int f(x)\mathrm{d}x=F(x)+C$$

But, this doesn't imply $C=2C$, in general .

Note that, if we already use/define the notation $C$, basically we need to write $2C\longmapsto C$, not $2C=C$ .